# How can I keep Stack Overflow clones out of my Google search results?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, creative-commons, clone

What is the best way to keep the various Stack Overflow clones and aggregators out of my Google search results?

*Sites that are not to be named*; I'm looking at you.

They are seriously messing up my work flow.

Comment: Should go probably to the webapps SE, since it's a question about using google.

Comment: can you provide the specific query terms you're using that are problematic?

Comment: What exactly is your "work flow"? Define "seriously messing up". All the content on Stack Overflow and their sites is CC-Wiki. Sites are free to use it with attribution. What is the real problem here?

Comment: I think Google fixed this when they went after content farms.  I used to see clone sites, but I haven't in a while.

Comment: I agree with James, I haven't seen one in a while. But if you do, you can report it [at this MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here).

Comment: For future readers, note that @Pops' comment is outdated. Per [animuson's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/335251): "You should only [report the site to us](/contact) if **the site is a proxy.** Whatever the purpose of the site actually is, malicious or not, proxies represent a serious security threat to our site. Sometimes they even start showing up in Google results and users click on them not realizing that they aren't actually on Stack Overflow. Users get confused, or try to log in and accidentally send sensitive information to a third-party service."

Comment: @V2Blast you know users with mod priviledges can delete comments, right ;)

Comment: @Luuklag: Yes, I'm aware. I figured I'd explain the change here, rather than just silently deleting Pops' comment :P

Answer (score 13):

**Editor note**: There used to be a first-party Google Chrome extension that would block sites from your search results, but at some point it was abandoned. Original answer below for historical value.

---

<s>The newest Google Chrome extension : [Personal Blocklist extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) as described in [the Official Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-chrome-extension-block-sites-from.html).</s>

[image: Extension in Action]

Comment: And some handy URLs to add: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2218528

Comment: The link to the extension is broken, here are the new links:
[for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklistnot-by/cbbbhelcpfjhdcncigdlkabmjbgokmpg?hl=en-US) and [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/personal-blocklist/)

Comment: @feeela in case you see this comment, please post new answer with the third party extension, it does not fit as edit of this answer. (Many people suspect external extensions, this answer gave "original" extension which was legit.)

Comment: For uBlock Origin there's filter lists: https://github.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter - you can request to add the ones you found

Answer (score 10):

I created a list of these garbage sites, and a description on how to use it in a blocker:

> https://github.com/AMV007/stack_overflow_clones

Comment: Works perfect, no more garbage in my searches

Comment: Awesome; just import the list into your tool/ extension/ userscript of choice and go from there.

Answer (score 4):

To include a domain, add this to the search terms:

```
site:stackoverflow.com
```

To exclude a domain:

```
-site:geeksforgeeks.org
```

---

In Firefox, you can set up a keyword search by creating a bookmark such as:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%s
```

And add a search keyword prefix such as `"so"` so that you can search in the address bar via:

```
so How to sum list in Python
```

---

Alternatively, here's some bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:q = "" + (window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text); if (!q) q = prompt("You didn't select any text.  Enter a search phrase:", ""); if (q!=null) location=("http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=site:stackoverflow.com " + escape(q.replace(/\"/g,""))).replace(/ /g, "+"); void 0
```

Comment: Scripts like this are nothing more than a band-aid generally.

Comment: I think the goal is to be able to search the entire web which would include StackOverflow but just excluding a few specific domains such as the ones suggested by sou desu ne.

Comment: To exclude a domain, prepend a minus: `-site:geeksforgeeks.org`.

Comment: Of course; but they keep appearing like snails after rain. You'd like a solution which doesn't involve endlessly playing whack-a-mole with new parasitic domains.

Answer (score 4):

There are different browser add-ons that could help. If you use Firefox there is the [SurfClarity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/search%20filter) add-on and for Google Chrome there is a [Search Filter](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ddgjlkmkllmpdhegaliddgplookikmjf) add-on that both seem to do what you want but at the browser level. I agree that it would be handy if Google had some type of personalization for this that would stick around with your Google account regardless of the machine or browser you are using.

Answer (score 4):

The [uBlacklist](https://github.com/iorate/ublacklist) extension ([Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe) / [Firefox Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublacklist/)) provides blocking of custom sites from a number of search engines, including Google and Duck Duck Go.

It allows you to add "Subscriptions" which are lists of sites to be blocked. One of these lists is a list of [Stack Overflow clones](https://github.com/arosh/ublacklist-stackoverflow-translation), which appears to be updated every few days.

Answer (score 3):

Using so called "Operators".

Write `site:stackoverflow.com` on the end of query for every query.

For example:

```
how to write HelloWorld site:stackoverflow.com
```

Google will do the rest.

Comment: BTW. Why you are using Google? Duckduck.com will do the same without tracking you.

Comment: Unfortunately, "`site:`" does *not* work in [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo). A mitigation is to include the site name in the search query as the site name is often in every 'title' tag, e.g. "Stack Overflow", "Wiktionary", or "Wikipedia". And Google Search now (2021) violates the contract by returning results from other sites anyway.

Comment: Oh, come on: https://i.imgur.com/LGP4lGk.png

Comment: @MichałKuliński DuckDuckGo does not have the same results quality.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the search bar in https://stackexchange.com

See:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/

Comment: Oh good, they finally flipped over to using Google site-search; much better results than the SO search.