# Report high-Google-ranking Stack Exchange content copiers here

Tags: discussion, seo, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

**NB** The following is a community-generated list of web pages that display Stack Exchange content and rank higher in search results than the original SE posts they copy. It is no longer being maintained, because the procedure for reporting such sites has changed; see the duplicate for more information.

For the original instructions, see this question's [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/71820/revisions). You may also be looking for [the post for reporting sites that use Stack Exchange content illegally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) (that is, without following attribution guidelines).

Comment: What about results varying from country to country? Some copycat sites seem to get ranked higher than SO in the U.S. only

Comment: Perhaps I should learn to stop using stackoverflow in my programming queries?

Comment: Shouldn't we report at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport instead? Even when NOT violation Google's rules, reports might convince Google that their users are not happy with these search results?

Comment: Who is to say Stack Overflow should always rank higher. They are allowing the content as CC-Wiki and if another site provides the content in a better way, what's the fuss?

Comment: I guess this is to understand why SO is ranking below the scrapers. I hope it's not to demean the "scrapers" themselves. Because if the scrapers are attributing and following the license, they are doing no wrong. I hope Jeff meant to ask, "Send me the links of those ranking higher. I want to see what they are doing right."

Comment: @Arjan To give a bad analogy,that is like giving away free Yellow T shirts and then asking people to throw water balloons on those wearing yellow T shirts. Google automatically discredits duplicate content and SO requires attribution so that generally means incoming links from the scraper. So SO should rank higher more often than not.

Comment: Is Cutts talking about this issue [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/algorithm-change-launched/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+mattcutts/uJBW+(Matt+Cutts:+Gadgets,+Google,+and+SEO)&utm_content=Google+Reader)?

Comment: Confound sites like efreedom. If they're evil, that's reason enough to not like them. If they're not, I can't get a slice o' that. Either way it's a losing proposition.

Comment: Stack Exchange should have a "wholesale copying" prohibition. Many products have this; they allow liberal use of their IP, but not if you're just making a clone; you must also provide substantial additional value. Copying and pasting the entirety of an SE site is just a lazy attempt to profit off the backs of others, and disrespects the work all of the contributors (and SE corporate) put into their content, attribution or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is it even possible to have such a prohibition on CC BY-SA content? Or are you proposing changing to a different license?

Comment: @PopularDemand: IANAL, but the CC BY-SA license states that the "collective work" (i.e. the entire site) does not have to abide by the license, although I suppose it does by SE's interpretation of the license. If it does, copiers should state that the material is lifted from [the SE site], in accordance with the license. If it doesn't, I think you can make the case for a wholesale copy restriction. Each page should have a link to the CC BY-SA license. Each contribution should be individually attributed. http://www.qandasystem.info does none of these things.  It's just my opinion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No way. That would have been a deal-breaker for me. Before participating, one of the things I checked was that in case Stack Overflow went down or bad, someone could fork the site with the existing content. If Stack Exchange ever decides to use a more restrictive license for new content, I'm out.

Comment: Could this question be used to advertise your own scraper site?

Comment: @prusswan I suppose so, but the people who read this page are probably not going to be interested in switching from the Genuine Article to a scraper. And I personally keep an eye on new posts, making sure to remove any direct links to scrapers, so that the copycats don't get any Google PageRank boost for being listed.

Answer (score 20):

`http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/7587/why-does-crash-my-page`

is a direct copy of [Why does $($) crash my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585840/why-does-crash-my-page). So far, other than in the retained links from the sister sites, I do not see any citations or links to SO or the original question. In other words, they do not follow the the content attribution rules.

Another case: `http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/6463/beating-jquery-addiction-which-jquery-methods-are-easily-translated-into-pure-javascript`

is a copy of [Beating jQuery addiction: Which jQuery methods are easily translated into pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005211/beating-jquery-addiction-which-jquery-methods-are-easily-translated-into-pure-j) *which the owner of the site takes credit for... methinks Felix Kling will not be impressed.*

Also, they're changing names for obfuscation. The questions/answers remain the same, however.

A trick they're using: the date on their site is **two months older** than SO's. They're making it look like SO copied them.

Here is their Google ranking when searching for the question I noted above:
[image]

Upon further investigation, `http://www.advancesharp.com/` appears to copy most if not all of its content from SO. Also, it appears to belong to [this SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586227/ali-adravi). Here is his question about scraping content from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3448821/561731

To further fuel my rage on all of this: here is a random collection of links (there might be more; I just clicked on a few recent ones) that show the user plugging his ripped site. (The answers at least seem to be unique in these cases, but that is only when searching them against SO and not other sites.)

[Need date format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135550/need-date-format-in-sql-server/10839770#10839770)
[Date format pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857500/date-format-pattern/10839686#10839686)
[Update without first selecting data in LINQ 2 SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399379/update-without-first-selecting-data-in-linq-2-sql/10823328#10823328)
[Update using LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909960/update-using-linq/10754004#10754004)

It really grinds my gears that he is making money for other people's hard work, so I've been researching his other questions. `http://advancesharp.com/Questions/16352/how-can-i-group-by-a-datetime-field-only-using-the-date-w` is a direct copy of http://forums.asp.net/t/1802521.aspx/1?How+can+i+group+by+a+datetime+field+only+using+the+date+without+the+time+.

[I will be contacting asp.net with this information next](http://forums.asp.net/post/5035500.aspx).

Comment: Well after flagging the answers as SPAM they were removed so the 4 links I posted just make me look like I'm going crazy!

Comment: no, users with enough rep see deleted answers. it's all fine, you don't need to fear that you loose your face here ;)

Comment: huh, looks like he took down the examples you mentioned. Sneaky bastard...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I have noticed some as well (I reported him on two answers in Meta for coverage) and updated the other answer. You can still find scraped content if you look. Take a few of the higher rated Q/As and google search the title / content and you will find the same content from other site.s

Comment: "A trick they're using: the date on their site is two months older than SO's. They're making it look like SO copied them." Is Google seriously this stupid? Why isn't they simply using the timestamp of indexing? I'm sure SO was indexed earlier...

Comment: yes this is what they (or he) does. The names of the users and sometimes the titles are changed. Sometimes answers / questions have small parts omitted as well (a few words here and there, or an image)

Answer (score 12):

```
http://www.x2x1.com/faq/
```

This site is a blatant rip-off.  Even their layout is similar.  Most (if not all) questions are ripped verbatim from Stack Overflow.  I Googled the text from one question, and Stack Overflow was the first result; this site was third and fourth.

Google this: `TypeError: unbound method can_move() must be called with O_shape`.

Original question: [Python: Display Shape from Tetris Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995690/drawing-blocks-tetris) at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995690/drawing-blocks-tetris`

Knockoff URL: `http://www.x2x1.com/show/8995690.aspx` (even the question ID is the same *facepalm*)

[image]

Comment: No attribution *and* they're spamming all kinds of social bookmark links *and* hiding accepted answers behind a membership wall... that's definitely infringing on the CC-wiki license.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing on that site but illegal content >:(

Comment: The site seems to be owned by some dude in China.  http://www.whois.net/whois/x2x1.com

Comment: You can try emailing `Abuse@hichina.com`, this seems to be where he bought the domain from.

Answer (score 10):

`readmespot.com` They seem to abide by the license: they link back to the question and to each post author, they have a footer indicating that the content is aggregated from SO/SU/SF and under CC-wiki.

Found by searching ["securing file system for secure sftp server"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22securing+file+system+for+secure+sftp+server%22). The copy of the question on readmespot is returned first, then the other results on that site, then results on SF with 1: a question that links to it, 2: a tag page, 3: the question with this title.

[image: www.google.com/search?q=%22securing+file+system+for+secure+sftp+server%22]

Next down is a [license violator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962). Nice to see that at least the legal content scraper did better than the illegal and visually aggressive one.

Comment: no readmespot showing up now, but I do see some *.info which is never good.

Answer (score 7):

**http://RQGG.net**

`http://www.rqgg.net/hohohohohohohoh/Scrblnrd3.html`

Given, most of these are a few spots behind Stack Overflow, but a few are higher.

Comment: We believe to have killed the feed for this bot.  Thanks for the report.

Comment: I googled my name `"Rocket Hazmat"` (with the quotes around it), and this... site was the 5th result.  It shows SO questions and answers with no links to SO at all!  The even have `user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA with Attribution required` at the bottom of their site (what tools)!

Comment: OH MY!  It's worse than I thought!  They have `Site Design / Logo © 2013 Rqgg, user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA with Attribution required.` at the bottom of their site.  Look familiar? ... (`site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required`)

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I discovered this same domain has lifted Q&A from other sites in the Stack Exchange network, including apple.stackexchange.com and money.stackexchange.com.  Found some of my own posts at RQGG by way of Google when I did a vanity search.  See `www.rqgg.net/hohohohohohohoh/Chris%20W.%20Rea.html`

Comment: I posted this at [the other list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188568/146482) since they do not link back to the original page

Answer (score 5):

**http://codeblow.com/**

This site is stealing SO content without attributing.

Example 1:

I searched Google for "Apache Filesmatch" and got `http://codeblow.com/questions/apache-filesmatch/`, which is a copy of the SO question [Apache FilesMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181700/apache-filesmatch).

Example 2 (merged in from [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137275/131713) that was originally posted separately):

`http://codeblow.com/questions/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-sqlite-database-to-be-used-in-android/`

was found when searching for

[Get Latitude and Longitude from SQLite database for use in Android MapOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7286746/50776)

Comment: @PopularDemand Must be a search bubble or whatever it is called.

Comment: codeblow is also modifying the content by using synonyms for some words to avoid being an exact duplicate (even if it doesn't make sense, like replacing "drivers" with "motorists" even though it refers to software drivers)

Answer (score 5):

**http://www.qandasystem.info**

```
http://www.qandasystem.info/gaming/do-i-need-to-grab-every-orb/
```

is a to-the-letter copy of [this question from Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44495/do-i-need-to-grab-every-orb), and comes up fifth in a Google search for the name.

The answerer's username is still there, but that's about it in terms of "attribution."

It's kind of strange that it's being touted as a "Q&A system" when they're using a WordPress blog format (thoughts/comments) to post "answers"....

---

In fact, it looks like at least the gaming category on this site is entirely composed of ripped content from Arqade: `http://www.qandasystem.info/gaming/`.

**Edit:** Looking at the rest of the site, it appears that all of it is ripped from Stack Exchange. Copy and paste any of the question titles into Google and watch what comes up.

Answer (score 3):

Site stealing SE posts without attribution:

`http://vniup.com/index.php/linux-unix/unable-to-access-linuxskbuff-h.html`

Here is the question (and answers) they stole:

[Unable to access linux/skbuff.h](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28139/unable-to-access-linux-skbuff-h)

Comment: Content theft alone doesn't make an answer good for this question; it also has to rank above the corresponding SE question on Google. You're looking for [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here). But don't bother re-reporting it, because there's already a post about vniup on that question.

Answer (score 3):

Search text in Google:

> jquery ui accordion copy item shows multiple active Animate Items Added / Removed To Accordion

and

> "jquery ui accordion copy item shows multiple active"

Scraper site above Stack Overflow:

`http://javascript.bigresource.com/jQuery-Animate-items-added-removed-to-Accordion-JdbyerR80.html`

Stack Overflow question:

[Animate items added/removed to a jQuery Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656195/animate-items-added-removed-to-a-jquery-accordion)

Do not see attribution/link to SO question in the scraper site.

Did not see the SO question in the first eight pages of Google results.

I forgot, in my haste, to ignore this other site in the search results — as I most often do — as they have horrid performance and often/most of the time clicking on the "replies" to the questions on **their** site gives you not found bombs due to their **horrid** performance... and I really see **no** value in their site.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847645/is-there-a-best-practice-to-not-forget-svn-add-new-files-with-tortoise-svn) and Googled for ["tortoisesvn sharptooth"](http://www.google.ru/search?q=tortoisesvn+sharptooth). I got a bunch of other result, and the 8th result was on QuestionHub.com: `http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/1847645`, which is a scraped version of the question I tried to find, but there wasn't the original question anywhere on the first page of the resultset.

Also I wanted to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3360900/57428) and Googled for [`"debug heap" sharptooth attach`](http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22debug+heap%22+sharptooth+attach) - there're no results on stackoverflow.com in the output, but there's a link to this thing `http://tech-question.com/visual-c-difference-between-start-with-without-debugging-in-release-mode-355427` (that btw looks like violating the license...).

Comment: no repro at all now

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago, I posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49298/can-i-play-seiklus-in-windowed-mode) on Gaming. Having not received a correct answer, I decided to do some Google searching, and stumbled upon `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/gamer/can-i-play-seiklus-in-windowed-mode.html`. It would seem they stole my question, as well as the answers. I've looked, but I can't find an attribution anywhere on their page.

Also, in case it's important, it was the fifth result in the Google search.

Comment: I'm always astounded how ugly the copycat sites always are.

Comment: I like how the largest tag in that site's tag cloud is "Possible Duplicate."

Answer (score 2):

This blog post incorporates one of my Stack Overflow answers, copied in full, with no link, attribution, mention of me or of Stack Overflow:

`http://www.dkphp.com/questions-2/pros-and-cons-of-using-a-cursor-in-sql-server.html`

If you wait for the annoying "like" dialog to access this "premium" stolen content, you'll find that the portion of the post directly below "The Answer" is a direct copy - links and all - of my answer here:

[Pros and cons of using a cursor (in SQL server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319918/pros-and-cons-of-using-a-cursor-in-sql-server/9322937#)

This was not scraped or automated, or pulled via an API - this was very clearly done by hand, incorporated into the user's own blog post as if it were part of his own work.

I did not find this blog post through Google, but it was just posted today (I discovered it via trackback). So it doesn't appear above Stack Overflow for relevant search terms today, but it still seems to violate the terms of use.

(I brought this up as a new question, *[Answers lifted and published elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133566/)*.)

Answer (score 1):

No links back or attribution whatsoever:

Main site: `http://downloadeeebooks.blogspot.ca/`

Specific instance: `http://downloadeeebooks.blogspot.ca/2012/05/modify-presentation-of-element-in.html`

Original SO question: [Modify presentation of element in a TabularInline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390749/modify-presentation-of-element-in-a-tabularinline)

[image: screenshot of google search]

Answer (score 1):

`gamingqna.blogspot.com` is in partial violation of our cc-by-sa license. Most pages do have author links, `http://gamingqna.blogspot.it/2011/07/where-does-audiosurf-put-corkscrews.html` e.g. doesn't.

Could they possibly be doing this *by hand?* The mind boggles.

Answer (score 1):

One more site that is stealing Stack Overflow content without attributing: `http://www.1771.in/`. They are using fake author names with answers and not mentioning Stack Overflow.

I found [one of my SO answers](http://www.1771.in/grouping-jquery-wrap-every-x-elements-in-div.html) on that site.

Comment: Post this on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here

Comment: @torrentialcoding You don't have to wait for the OP in cases like this, you can just do it yourself. This time, there's no need, it's already been reported there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137304/131713

Comment: @PopularDemand Thanks. I will make sure I do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**http://diy101.net/**

A full copy of DIY.SE minus the footer. It seems to be read-only.

Answer (score 1):

**hows.info**

> Ruby openssl dgst -sha1 -sign

was the search term.

While it's not necessarily above the fold, this is an obscure enough search that there are few meaningful result subject lines, and one of them was hows.info copy of the same article on so.

[image]

Original image link: http://twitpic.com/cefqjg

Comment: It's now three months later, I just tried to reproduce this, and the first TLDs I got were, in order: ruby-forum.com, ruby-doc.org, whitequark.org (x2), itags.org, fossies.org, apidoc.com, rubydoc.info, bitcointalk.org and redhat.com. I didn't see hows.info or any SE sites anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/03/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds/`

is an unattributed copy of the Stack Overflow question

[How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

I found it via a simple Google search for the title "How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?".

There's no mention of Stack Overflow on the page other than two references in the question itself (including "This is my first Stackoverflow question"). The answers, of which there are several, do not appear. The added footer:

> This entry was posted in C / C++ and tagged OSX, SET, SO, VALUE, VALUES on March 26, 2013 by bartol.

is mostly incorrect; the questioner is ChrisD, not bartol, and the "tags" do not resemble those on the original question.

I haven't looked at the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

`http://cookingqna.blogspot.de/`

No attribution at all. Also no indication who the responsible person for the site is, which is a violation of German law (and the site gets served to me from a German domain—yes I know that this is just Blogspot changing the domain, but maybe this is a legal way to show teeth to them).

Thank you [David Wallace](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10381/david-wallace) for noticing it.

Comment: I actually do see very discreet attribution pointing back to the author profiles on SE, and at the bottom of each post is a "more discussion" link that directs you back to the original question on Seasoned Advice. So on first glance, it looks like they actually are following our attribution laws, but definitely in a kind of shady way. Someone here at Stack HQ will look into this further, though.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for something I dimly remembered one one of the StackExchange sites (which one? Math? Security? Crypto? Maybe Google knows ...),
I Googled this:

```
stackexchange encryption "initialization vector" same file different ciphertext
```

and (near the bottom of) the first page of Google results includes

```
"Should I use an initialization vector (IV) along with my encryption?"
http://s340.codeinspot.com/q/341449
```

These people seem to be complying with all the attribution requirements listed at "
[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) ", so as far as I can tell they are legal.

(I didn't know there was way to [search all StackExchange sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/) until *hours* after I did that Google search).

Answer (score 0):

`www.yulebiao.com`

Copying content from stackoverflow, without date or attribution.
Furthermore, they write in the bottom "Copyright (C) 2013 Yulebiao.com - All rights reserved".

Searched for "ggplot connecting line space".

[image: Screenshot of google search]

Original content: [connecting lines between means of factors in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097107/connecting-lines-between-means-of-factors-in-ggplot2)

Copied: `http://www.yulebiao.com/questions/15097107/connecting-lines-between-means-of-factors-in-ggplot2`

Answer (score 0):

**http://088062.com/**

They pretend to be the site where you can ask the questions, but there's no link for it. They remove user names and machine-translate the content to German. No information about the source, they pretend it's theirs.

A little flower, from `http://088062.com/about`:

> 088062 ist Teil der Stapel Exchange-Netzwerk

"Stapel" is the translation of "Stack" into German.

Comment: What were the offending Google search terms?

Comment: I think I should have posted it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here
I can't replicate it with my home laptop, but that portal is impudent enough to copy even original SE favicons and logos