# Stackoverflowerizer update

Tags: support, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

There's a new scraping site on the scene that Stackoverflowerizer doesn't redirect: `http://www.apacheserver.net/`

Comment: My eyes. MY EYES!!!

Answer (score 2):

There's a [special post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962) for this, you can update it with your information.

PS Not sure if anybody benefits from that data, though.

**edit**
Link is fixed.

Comment: OK, yeah, it's been listed there, which is good.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, and YMMV…

On 2 January, [I added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/24611/timeline) apacheserver.net to the big list at [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/).

On 8 January, [user155464](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155464/user155464) added [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#comment-179753):

> apacheserver.net fully complies with TOS. It uses the API, the official API has a link to question in the form of stackoverflow.com/questions/##/timeline Also as far a links to migrated questions, the API does not provide the username or ID or author for those types of questions. Here is the example of data provided by the API: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/4634197 and this is example of migrated question from API (notice no author in it): http://api.superuser.com/1.0/questions/220732

On 9 January, the same user [added an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here/74442#74442) to the question [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here/), saying:

> I have been following this whole development and it looks like you are at war with sites that use your own API.
>   …
>   I think if someone complies with the attribution requirements and links back to original, you should not treat those sites like some sort of criminals. After all, the 'mashups' is the new buzz word on the web.
>   …
>   You (SO) are probably the only site I know that offers the API and then go on a witch hunt against those who uses it, even those who uses it properly.

Comment: Nice find! It appears to be complying with the licence (the footer is incorrect -- it says the licence is cc-wiki, but mentions nothing about attribution), however the site design is pretty much a bad copy of SE, which is an issue unto itself.