# Why is my question posted on apacheserver.net without any notification?

Tags: support, guidelines

I placed a question on Stack Overflow, and I was searching the same topic on Google, and I discovered same duplicate question is also posted on apacheserver.net, and I did not receive any notification or acknowledgment that this is going to happen. Why it is like that?

- Stack Overflow question: [Redirect on the basis of referer HTTP_REFERER htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151385/redirect-on-the-basis-of-referer-http-referer-htaccess)
- Duplicate question on Apacheserver.net: http://www.apacheserver.net/q63341/Redirect-on-basis-referer-HTTP_REFERER-htaccess

Please let someone know me the reasons.

Comment: Related: [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Answer (score 6):

The content of Stackoverflow is [CC-licensed](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), that means it can be freely copied as long as the [appropriate attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) is given.

By posting to SO you're agreeing that your content is put under this specific license.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not particularly care for these "content farms" and has released a chrome browser plugin to help oust them from the first page of search results. See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/80509#80509) to the question [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) for further info.