# What is "www.qickfix.com" and why do they have copies of SO data?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, clone

I was trying to Google for [my old question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785398/is-there-a-way-to-communicate-application-context-to-a-db-connection-in-non-sybas). One of the results looked very fishy to me:

`http://www.qickfix.com/topic.php?id=160953`

> sql - Is there a way to communicate application context to a DB connection in non-Sybase DB servers 
>   (similar to set_appcontext in Sybase)? - Stack Overflow (3 posts)

That URL basically seemed to be someone wholesale copying of actual Q&A (and more) data from SO.

The site's banner calls identifies it as "expert.tc."

Any clue who they are and if what they are doing is legal?

Searching on Meta and just Googling didn't seem to yield any useful results.

Comment: Report it in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here?answertab=votes#tab-top and also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: @agf - Those are good places to report the site so that SO can optimize their SEO and learn from other implementations, but it's far more important to report the site in [this list of license-infringing sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824).

Comment: @KevinVermeer Thanks, I looked for that but didn't see it when I posted that comment.

Comment: @agf - posted to 71820

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Stackoverflow releases monthly a [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) containing all questions, answers, etc. That's publicly accessible and anyone can download that. So this explains how they got the data.

Many "shady" people use the data dump to re-create stackoverflow websites, usually with tons of ads, in the hopes of getting hits from google and then money from the ads.

This is 100% legal and allowed (although I would say "immoral") as long as the [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) - which requires attribution - is respected. Since the particular website you linked has no attribution (no link back to stackoverflow or to the authors) it's copyright infringement.

Comment: Are you sure it's "copyright infringement"? I'd call it "license violation"...

Comment: @Padded: the license allows you to copy the content without infringing the copyright, so if you don't follow it the license doesn't apply and thus it's copyright infringement.. Or at least I think so :S

Comment: this actually isn't happening in the wild, though -- if you are clever (for small values of clever..) you can construct a search containing a very rare phrase (hint: think guids) in a very early stack overflow question. Doing this shows that almost nobody has the full dump out there.

Answer (score 13):

We keep a running list of sites we have discovered to be in violation of the license [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers). I've added this new offender to my personal list of offenses to look into.

Often, sites using Stack Overflow content are simply not aware of the infringement and they bring their sites up to snuff promptly as soon as I send them a message pointing it out. Sometimes... they don't. But that's another story.

Comment: I don't think anyone goes to this amount of trouble to pretend they're their own community by replicating "our" content without at least an inkling that what they're doing is downright rude.

Comment: @Tom Oh, they know it's *rude*. They also know it's content that's frequently searched and that selling ads on their copycat sites can be lucrative, so they don't *care*. We don't mind them being that kind of rude as long as they attribute properly.

Comment: I do, lack of any legal basis notwithstanding. I spend a lot of time on my answers for _Stack Overflow_, and I'm aware that they are CC but I wish that they weren't. It's not enough to make me stop contributing, but it's close. Increasingly so, actually. I don't spend several hours a day writing awesome answers so some nameless opportunist can make money off me and my friends.

Comment: Wow, this post is very interesting (honestly I didn't read it, I just want the sailboat thingy)