# Should I report (does any one care) when another site rips off Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copyright, plagiarism

I was looking for some way to speed up automapper and I found this question:

[Need to speed up automapper...It takes 32 seconds to do 113 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208550/need-to-speed-up-automapper-it-takes-32-seconds-to-do-113-objects)

That was not really my issue so I kept looking down the list of my google results.

I got sucked in by another site that seemed promising.

http://s25.codeinspot.com/q/1704766

But the title was really just the first line of the SO question and the text was a fully copy from SO.  I usually just ignore those, but I was annoyed that they sucked me in, so I thought I would make sure they attributed their content to StackOverflow (like they are supposed to).

I did a ctrl + F and could not find the words "stack" or "overflow" on the page.

So, my question is, does this really matter/anyone care?  If so, how should I report such things?  Is it just by posting here that I have done that?  Or is there an email I should send the site info to?

Comment: well if you click on the OP name in the second site it brings you to SO

Comment: @talnicolas - does that count as attributing the content to SO?  According to this post by Jeff, I don't think so: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/  (It needs to "Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow")

Comment: At the end of the question there is also a "Source" link which brings you to the SO question

Answer (score 8):

It does look like they fail the first directive of [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.

If they rank higher than Stack Overflow in your search results you can [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here).

There's also [a big list of scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/1288) that I don't see that site listed on, so you can add them there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the email that is linked to the bottom of each Stack Exchange site.

[image: screenshot]

In that site, there is no indication that the questions are taken from Stack Overflow, and the links to the user profile and the original questions are shown just on some questions.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: boooo your drawings are too photoshopped :-P

Comment: Cough, cough… I didn't use Photoshop. `:-)`

Comment: But you didn't use freehand arrows either ;-)