# someone stealing SE questions?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

I asked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28139/unable-to-access-linux-skbuff-h) question on Unix and Linux SE a week ago. Now I find this webpage with the exact question and the answer given [here](http://vniup.com/index.php/linux-unix/unable-to-access-linuxskbuff-h.html). WTF! is this stealing ? some kind of a phony business ? Please explain!

Comment: doesn't seem to be any attribution there...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824

Comment: @awoodland man I agree .. but still I guess its slightly unethical to blindly crawl the web to generate content for a website. dont you think ? didnt know such models of business's existed !

Comment: Yeap, that's repulsive to say the least. No attribution anywhere, ads everywhere. Kill, kill, destroy. Notice that @awoodland gave you two links, one saying that if the CC is followed is ok, and another to report sites like the one you found.

Comment: And their CAPTCHA right now is the Greek word for "crap". How appropriate...

Comment: *Lots* of sites are stealing SE questions. Please do report any of them you see so the SE crew can take care of it through the proper channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People are allowed to copy SE site's content under CC-Wiki, which requires attribution. As they're not doing this it's up to SE.

[There's a thread here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here) that you can use to report them.

Comment: ya .. i looked at the question .. well .. such mischievous ppl exist in this world !!