# Is "Treasure Gourd" associated with stackoverflow?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)
>   [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

I've just found [a question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343773/50776) copied word for word on a site called "[Treasure Gourd](http://www.x2x1.com/show/8343773.aspx)"

This site has a similar feel as stackoverflow.  Is it a knockoff?

Comment: Probably a knock off. However I wouldn't worry about it unless they are copying Stack Exchange content without attribution.

Comment: _'Know someone who can answer?'_ Only no sharing, so not only will you have to know someone who can answer, but mess around with providing a link, or also call them to describe it to you, or use telepathy, or something else altogether magical to get it posted.

Comment: Well they've lifted my question and put it on their site with no mention of me or Stack Exchange?  I don't have any major problem with that.  But I thought stack exchange might...

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment a lot of the links on the site don't seem to work, possibly in early stages to see if it will work.

Comment: Wow, they're a Q&A site and a file hosting site in one.  They may be on to something...

Comment: Sites like that make me want to take a baseball bat to their servers

Comment: @JeffMercado looks like that does cover my question but I didn't see it when searching the meta. Can I vote to close my own question?

Comment: @AidanO: I believe you can.  As the owner of this question, you have the option to delete (but can't since it's upvoted) and close AFAIK.

Comment: See also [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Comment: :) Treasure Gourd | About Us • Contact Us • Log in • Log up