# Duplicate content: how to submit a website?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

[This page](http://loopingrecursion.com/?t=resizing) is directly copying your content. Is this allowed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) - see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here to report infringing sites (this one is already there).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are doing nothing illegal, since they have everything allright, based on [these](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) policies

- Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.   - passed (✔)
- Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345) - passed (✔)
- Show the author names for every question and answer   - passed (✔)
- Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username) - passed (✔)

Comment: Do they really satisfy requirement #1 though? Yes, they do link to the original question on SO, but I don't think the status bar content when you hover over a link counts as a visual indication, and I don't see anything else to show that the content comes from SO. (Unless the image at the top is supposed to indicate that, but it doesn't really.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: There's a big "Stack Overflow tag filter" title on the top.

Comment: Huh, I only see that on the site's home page, not on the page actually linked in the question.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Hmm, it is really discreet, but it's there after clicking the logo

Answer (score 1):

User content on Stack Exchange follows [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) license.

The [attribution policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/): mentions

> If you republish this content, we
> require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate
>    that the content is from Stack
>    Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server
>    Fault, or Super User in some way. It
>    doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a
>    discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original
>    question on the source site (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every
>    question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each
>    author name directly back to their
>    user profile page on the source site
>    (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink
> must point directly to our domain, and
> not use a tinyurl or any other form of
> obfuscation or redirection.
> Furthermore, the links must not be
> nofollowed.

Since the site follows all attribution guidelines, they aren't doing anything wrong. Sites which don't follow these guidelines can be reported in this question:

- [Report high-Google-ranking Stack Exchange content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)