# Is FatalWeb at all associated with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

I've started seeing some links appearing in Google to "Fatalweb" that look dangerously similar to Stack Overflow - it seems to be just a mirror of Stack Overflow with different question ids, and no mention about what it is or where it came from?!

Here's an example:

**On Stack Overflow:**

[How to serialize an object to send over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261227/c-how-to-serialize-an-object-to-send-over-network)

**On fatalweb:**

`http://fatalweb.com/questions/303338/c++++how+to+serialize+an+object+to+send+over+network`

They're the same page, complete with answers and everything!

Anyone know anything about it?

Comment: Looks like someone who took the content and is not abiding by the terms of use.

Comment: Add it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here

Comment: How does this DMCA thing work? I'll fire them and their web host a message demanding they take my contributions down (which is what I can demand as a private person). Bizarrely, the admin contact for the domain is a `sudhir.vis@facebook.com` that makes it look like the guy is affiliated with FB (which probably isn't true though)

Comment: `© fatalweb While using this site, you agree to have read and accepted our terms of use and privacy policy.` lol. That can surely be enforced...

Comment: @CodeInChaos I think that is pretty standard these days, though! Re DMCA - the domain hosting company is located in India, like the site itself. Rats...

Comment: It actually should go [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers).

Comment: @Pekka have you tried emailing web@fatalweb.com?

Comment: @Pekka also, anyone [can have facebook.com email address](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=224049364288051). :)

Comment: @Sha oh, they can? I didn't know that. Thanks for the hint!