# Does Stack Overflow do anything to prevent sites from mining its information?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search, rankings

I asked a question a short while ago on Stack Overflow that has yet to be answered. Today I Googled a similar phrase and the top ranked Google result was this page:

http://www.rsscockpit.com/article.do?action=show&id=2159783633

It seems this site is mining information from Stack Overflow. Can we do anything to prevent this?

Comment: As long as proper attribution is given (in line with the Creative Commons license) what's the problem?

Comment: The "Read more" link takes you to your Stack overflow question, it is made obvious that it is taken from Stack Overflow, I think it's legitimate according to the CC something licence.

Comment: Point taken.  However; perhaps my question should be more to the point of "is there anything we can do to prevent sites like this from being ranked higher than the originating content on Stack Overflow"?  My understanding is the Google algorithm should already be taking this into account but in this case it's not. So really I guess I'd like to know if these sorts of cases should be reported somewhere when they occur. Probably more a question for Google than Stack Overflow I suppose.

Comment: @Randyaa, You can report them to the team here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here

Comment: Randyaa what @Brandon said, but only if they don't provide proper attribution. Remember, there's a publicly available [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) and publicly available data dumps, redistributing Stack Exchange's content is encouraged, if the CC is followed.

Comment: Why would anyone need to mine anything? SE provides data dumps with all content in XML format.

Comment: @ConradFrix You mean "Furthermore, the links must **not** be nofollowed."

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I was going to nija edit but I just deleted my comment instead thanks for clarifying that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends on how you're defining "mining."

Stack Overflow (and more generally, Stack Exchange) encourage everyone to use their content by providing occasional [data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) and a convenient interface for those dumps called the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

On the other hand, SE is serious about [protecting its content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) from [those who abuse it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here); sometimes rather [aggressively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123875/131713).

As long as attribution rules are followed, though, mining is allowed, even encouraged.