# Another Scraping site

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Has anyone already noticed that this site (http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/) is scraping StackOverflow? Check it out:

- Original Question: [WCF: Should all datacontracts use the same namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562221/wcf-should-all-datacontracts-use-the-same-namespace)
- Scrapped Question: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/should-datacontracts-namespace-180084.aspx

P.S.: Not sure (don't remember) where I should report this kind of thing.