# Tips4All Stack Overflow ripoff?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

I don't know if this site is somehow associated with Stack Overflow, but I found it today Googling some things and **many**  if not all of its answers and questions are taken from Stack Overflow: `http://tips4all.net/`.

Comment: Unfortunately the Intarwebs are *full* of sites like that. Grrr...

Comment: isn't there anything that can be done??? that REALLY sucks

Comment: They need more ads on that site to be viable/attractive

Comment: Here's the WHOIS record: http://www.networksolutions.com/whois-search/tips4all.net . As you can see, it's registered to "nguyen huu hai" using all fake contact info. Their DNS registrar is actually in the US, though, so that's something.

Comment: They don't even make any attempt at maintaining the actual author names. They're all completely fabricated linking to some random "user" on the site.

Comment: See [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) and [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Comment: @animuson LOL, looks like Jon Skeet's noone compared to [Rajesh](http://tips4all.net/?ptype=author_answers&uid=6)! 288532 answers provided, he must be some sort of demigod. The naiveness of the site makes me smile

Comment: i really liked Rajesh's bio. not generic at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers) other meta [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) about sites that scrape SO / SE content.

Valued Associate [Abby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165581/abby-t-miller) keeps an eye on that and contacts the sites to get them to comply with our [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) . Thanks for the heads up; we'll add it to our list and look into it. Please continue to report any other scrapers you find that are not properly attributing content to SO.

Comment: and that was just on the first 2 pages of google results... i just went 5-10 pages into the search and... dear lord... thanks for the info

Comment: Oh, I think this is the first I've heard that it's actually someone's official job to keep tabs on that list and contact the sites. Yay for Abby!