# My Stack Overflow answers on another site with an author name other than me

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

I've found this [**link**](http://www.123people.com/) from Facebook and I was just trying to understand what that site is for. So I've visited the site and found a text box and it looked like to me that I can search something from that site if I write something on that text box and I wrote my name `sheikh heera` and pressed enter key.

It then gave me some result and I found my email address and my web link and also some other links (Facebook etc) but suddenly I saw a link to an answer on Stack Overflow:
[**grouping – jQuery wrap every X elements in div**](http://www.1771.in/grouping-jquery-wrap-every-x-elements-in-div.html). I clicked on it and it redirected me to a site other than Stack Overflow and I found that there is author name included with the answer (but nothing found from it) and all the contents of the page belong to Stack Overflow.

**My question is**: Is it legal and that possible to do that without help of Stack Overflow (there are lots of apps on Stack Overflow to read answers from SO and display to another site) and if it's not legal what shoud we do or not ?

Comment: Related - [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Comment: Related - [Stack Overflow Clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Comment: Is that legal to use a fake author name and also not mentioning about original site ?

Comment: Absolutely not - here are the guidelines with regard to the Creative Commons licence... - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/.  All content on the Stack Exchange network falls under this CC licence.

Comment: Related: [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846)

Comment: I've posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here/139839#139839) an answer as suggested by users here, please take a look at this and you may edit it if you think it's not right. Thanks.