# Is "Q&A System" an official product of the SE network?

Tags: discussion, intellectual-property

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Yesterday, I stumbled upon an answer I gave on ITSec.SE, but on a completely different website: http://www.qandasystem.info/security/design-of-a-state-machine-model-to-solve-conflict-of-interest-in-computer-security/

After investigating a bit further, it seems that this site is just mirroring questions and answers from the SE network, in different categories, with no mention whatsoever to SE.

Is this website related in any way to SE? In any case, I don't appreciate the fact that there are ads on the website, meaning that the author is making money on author's people contribution.

Comment: Related - [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

Comment: And here is the "original" post for reference - [Design of a state machine model to solve conflict of interest in Computer Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11222/design-of-a-state-machine-model-to-solve-conflict-of-interest-in-computer-securi)

Comment: @Lix: Thanks, this website is actually already flagged, I've been searching for "Q&A system" instead of directly the URL,  my bad! The question can be closed :)