# SO Unanswered question found on another site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)
>   [Report high-Google-ranking SE content copiers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here)

I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824505/can-a-luntbuild-schedule-skip-the-vcs-adapter-task) which hasn't been answered in about 3 weeks or so. But that is not a problem while I was searching again for the same question; I found that the same question is available at [this](http://www.1771.in/build-can-a-luntbuild-schedule-skip-the-vcs-adapter-task.html) site.

When i looked at the question it seems that the site would automatically pull questions and might be answers as well from SO; does that happen?

or this is just a coincidence and someone has copied it manually?

Comment: I know this has happened before, but I can't find the question...

Comment: Related: [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824#106824)

Comment: Not really an exact dupe, but all the info you are looking for is there. Short version: Any site can use SO's content, if they provide [proper attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). If not, and they are relatively high ranking on Google, report them on the dupe (and if they don't rank high on Google, don't bother). The scrapper you find is pretty lousy, I wouldn't bother with it...