# Is this site copycatting Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, attribution, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

While researching for a problem, I found a good starting point on Stack Overflow, and while further researching, I stumbled upon a kind of translated copy of this Q&A.

Here's the original post from Stack Overflow: [Is there any way to loop through a struct with elements of different types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1784782/1370465)

Here's the translated copy: http://de.softuses.com/215384

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld - saw it, based on it I would now definitely say, that this site is not properly using this content - or not? I adding it to this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/195164 - ok, someone was faster already http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152157/195164

Comment: I especially like their (seemingly machine-translated) warning about possible errors in their machine translation: "Hinweis: Der oben genannte Inhalt, automatische Übersetzung, vom Roboter werden Leseschwierigkeiten, und Grammatikfehler!" which roughly translates to "Notice: the above noted content, automatic translation, by roboter will reading difficulties, and grammar mistakes!"

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question: yes, the [do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171987/double-click-to-start-windows-service) [copy](http://de.softuses.com/290513) (and "translate") the content without attribution.

Comment: We have [a place for reporting sites that steal SE content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) (i.e. copy it without attribution) and [a different place for reporting sites that use SE content that show up higher in search results than the original posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here). If the site you found is neither of these, it's probably not offensive, strictly speaking.

Comment: @PopularDemand - thank, but I found it already thanks to Aleksander - and the site is on it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152157/195164.

Comment: Awesome! The system works!