# Noticed one of my edited post in another site

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Not sure if this had been noticed by the house. I edited the content and heading of one of my unanswered post today. While searching web for some information, I just noticed that the same question i had earlier asked is also appearing on another site that I had no clue of:

This is my post in edit mode [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19807767/revisions)

This is the site I found the same post [QueryPost](http://www.querypost.com/group-dynamic-list-using-jquery-mobile-list-divider/)

Is this something anyone else as seen before?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177) (ick, C&P fumble).

Comment: thanks for providing the link. I will read it

Comment: Do I delete this question since its duplicate?

Comment: No. It can serve as beacon for similar questions in the future.

Comment: Alright I will leave it. Much appreciated