# How to report sites/users that are plagiarising SO questions on other forums?

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism

I did a web search for my question and found that my exact SO question was plagiarised in a forum post by someone else. My question was unique and this is clearly a plagiarism of my question.

But then I realized, **the user of the other forum is posting lots of SO questions as their own!!!**

Is there anything that can be done about this practically?

See here:

http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/395457-java-how-synchronize-inside-interface-default-method-without-using.html

Answer (score 9):

The content you've posted on Stack Overflow (or other Stack Exchange sites) is available under [a Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  Anyone can re-use it, provided they follow the attribution requirements spelled out by the licensor. These requirements are listed at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/, and this user is not in fact following them.

On the other hand, the fact that e has linked back to the original post -- no real obfuscation, in other words -- indicates probable good intentions. Given notification of the exact requirements, e may very well edit the posts to conform.

If you can locate the user on SE, you can mention it here, or you could post at the forum you've identified. Alternatively, leave it up to SE, Inc. to contact the user or the forum owner.

Pekka voiced his suspicions below that good intentions are absent here. If you also believe that to be the case, then you should see [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) and follow the procedure outlined there, leaving it in SE, Inc.'s capable hands.

Comment: The crapton of garbage ads that get thrown in your face, and the fact that SO content seems to be systematically imported into that forum and there is hardly any original content, really eliminates the possibility of good faith to me. They probably just failed importing the answers from the data dump :)

Comment: You may well be right, @probablyPekka. I admit I didn't look around much past the linked question.

Comment: They're stealing stuff from all over - e.g. [this blog post](http://queforum.com/blogs/sanvi/4127-copy-constructors-assignement-operators-c.html) from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) I hope they're somewhere where the DMCA applies and go down in flames