# Why is my question appearing on other websites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I submitted a question on Stackoverflow:  [Python - C++ - Reading in 16bit .wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345689/c-reading-in-16bit-wav-files)

Googling last night, I came across this post: [queforum.com - C++ reading in 16bit .wav files](http://queforum.com/python/580290-python-c-reading-16bit-wav-files.html)

1) Why is my question on another site

2) Did I sign up for my information (even though it is only a question) to be shared with other forum communities on sites?

I might be missing the point here..

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: This particulate site is probably using your content illegally, but you should be aware that content posted on Stack Exchange is licensed under a Creative Commons license, so people on other sites are permitted to copy content from Stack Overflow as long as they follow the proper attribution rules.

Comment: They copied your question but cut off the code, *and* they missed the answer that was posted a few minutes later. They've managed to make forums *even worse*. [Actually, I'm not even mad. That's amazing.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xZEDe.jpg)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Who actually are they?

Comment: Some random scraper that throws ads up around other people's content. [This user](http://queforum.com/members/bigdata.html) has posted over 240,000 questions in the past year.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I wonder how many of those are homework questions ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That's just mindboggling. What possible good could it do to a community to have someone autofill it with all the worst of human behaviour that bubbles up on Stack Overflow? *We* don't want those questions and need to throw in all our community policing to keep the website attractive; why would you automatically scrape that stuff into your own forum?!

Comment: @KerrekSB Ads. More content = more places google searches can go to. More places = more clicks. More clicks = more views. More views = more ad money.

Comment: This particular site has already been reported, but for future reference see the linked instructions