# Parasiting sites

Tags: discussion

I just found my SO question published under different user name on different site:

http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/675999-java-log4j2-configuration-3-0-servlet.html

Is there chance to stop such content thieves? They do not have my allowance to publish SO question.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers