# Google now has a makeshift form to report high-ranking scrapers

Tags: discussion, seo, screen-scraping

Source: https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/439122708157435904

> Matt Cutts (@mattcutts) 11:39 AM 27 Feb 2014
>
> If you see a scraper URL outranking the original source of content in Google, please tell us about it: http://bit.ly/scraperspamreport

Here is the current meta question detailing the scraper reporting process: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

I wanted to notify the community team on the other end of that "contact us" link that this exists.

Comment: Well, that is awesome!

Comment: The Google form for reporting Scrapers no longer accepts submissions, so I guess this is now out of date.  Too bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, we found out about this yesterday. You may consider us notified. (I love how many people try to tell us these things! That's not sarcasm; it really, truly is nice to have so many people in the community who care about us.)

Please note that the definition of "scraper" that Matt Cutts and Google are using there is **not** identical to the definition of "SCRAPER" that I put in the linked meta post. Google's form is only for republishing sites that outrank the originals, not for republishers that are using their content unethically.