# Is this site, which seems to be copying the content from stackexchange sites, legal?

Tags: discussion

This website called [FAQoverflow](http://www.faqoverflow.com/) came to my attention. It looks like a full copy of the various StackExchange sites. It does not add any information beyond the original contents from StackExchange, and its sectionings look like they were somehow programmatically generated from the tags on the question. Is this legal? Does StackExchange acknowledge this? It is scary because I can find my own contribution to the StackExchange sites copied on FAQoverflow, which I never knew before.

Comment: Please check here and report it if you think it's copying stuff from Stack Exchange: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/152515) (bear in mind, people _can_ reproduce content as long as they **provide attribution** and use the same license as SE for the content you're using)

Comment: They seem to be doing it entirely right, linking back to the site, the posts, and the original author's account. So nothing scary, but an appropriate use of the data it seems.

Comment: @Bart They do acknowledge the original sites' name, but it looks like they are trying to make it look like their own content and as if the posters posted to their site.

Comment: If you look at it, the posts say (for example) *"{ asked by R. Martinho Fernandes }"*. Where that line is linking back to the original post and the original author's account. Further than that the site states it's assembled from SE data. Keep in mind that all content has a CC-BY-SA license. So with proper attribution, which they seem to give, it's entirely fair to use it. I don't see anything bad here, though I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @sawa [This thing](http://i.imgur.com/hyqPfru.png). Valid concern though; I'm going to edit that answer.

Comment: This has been [re-asked on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266586/is-faqoverflow-part-of-stack-exchange-websites), and got [an answer from the developer behind FaqOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266627/122607).