# How share a deleted post (with someone interested in, but having no access)?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I know a person who would like to read one of my deleted post (more precisely, the comments on it), unfortunately he has no access to it.

**Question**: How can I share my deleted post with this person?

Comment: You could just make a screenshot?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes sure it's possible, but not very convenient, because the post and the comments are very very lengthy. I would like to allow to this person an access to it, as I can see it myself.

Comment: There is no such option. You can see it because you gained the 10k+ *Access To Moderator Tools* privilege. Until that other user gains the same privilege, they cannot see the post for themselves.

Comment: The copy of a deleted post could be on some of the [scraper sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers). See the discussion of somewhat related question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/are-there-some-possibillities-for-users-below-10k-to-see-deleted-posts-of-other/13329#13329).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a post is deleted, and the other user doesn't have the 10k+ reputation to see deleted posts, your options are:

- find a cached copy. If it was deleted recently, Google may still have a copy; put the full URL into the google search box with the term `cache:` prefixed to it. Or you can search the [Internet archive](http://archive.org/web/) for a copy. If such copies exist, they may have archived a version that doesn't have the latest revisions and comments, of course.
- if the post was deleted after the most recent data dump to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you can query for the post and its comments there. The data dump is updated once a week, on Sundays.

  Effectively, this is another temporary cache, and can be just as outdated. Changes made or comments added after the most recent dump are naturally not included.
- manually copy and paste the text elsewhere.
- take a screenshot of the post.

Comment: I've an other idea: a copy of the html source.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: that falls under the heading 'manually copy and paste' in my book.