# What is the tangible benefit to SE from legitimate "scraper" sites?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

We know that some sites are ["illegal" scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) that SE does not tolerate for obvious reasons.

But why does SE tolerate sites that re-post its content (scraped or from Data Dump) with correct attributions?

Is it simply that they cause no harm and costly to oppose?

Or do they bring some tangible benefits to SE? (extra traffic? branding? SEO?)

Please note that "we want the information available" is NOT a useful answer, but a slogan/high level goal. To be an answer, that phrase needs to be accompanied by SEO/traffic analysis which demonstrates that information is ACTUALLY more available - under a meaningful measurement (because, presumably, unless proven otherwise, 100% users who would obtain the info from a copycat site would equally likely obtain it from main SE had copycat site not existed).

Comment: Because the whole point of the site was to be open and a source of knowledge, so a suitable license was picked that allows for sharing. Sites that stick to the license are within that goal; knowledge is shared.

Comment: It would defeat the entire purpose of the site if people were unable to either access all of the information on the site, or to utilize the information they find here elsewhere.  It's not like you could have a licence that says, "You can do whatever you want with this context except try to compete with us".

Comment: @MartijnPieters - do you have specific evidence that existence of copycat sites **improves** the knowledge sharing (as opposed to makes it worse since now users's Google queries are split between 2 competing sources)

Comment: @DVK: the competing sources agree on the content, don't they? And good luck to getting a better ranking than Stack Overflow there; everyone links to Stack Overflow, including the legitimate license-abiding scrapers.

Comment: Just because **you** think *we want the information available* is a useless theoretical phrase doesn't mean it isn't true. If you listen to the early Stack Overflow podcasts or Jef Atwood's numerous blog posts on the subject it is very clear that that was the stated goal here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm not disputing that "we want information available" is the goal. I'm disputing a non-backed-up assertion that copycat sites contribute to (as opposed to detract from) that goal

Comment: @DVK: Whomever stated that they contribute? All I stated is that they don't infringe. How would you propose they'd be shut down? On what grounds?

Comment: @DVK: And all that appropriate linking back to the site has a massive effect on Google, no doubt.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The question explicitly allows for the possibility that they don't hurt enough to be worth the trouble fighting against. But BOTH halves of this statements need to be substantiated.

Comment: @DVK: note that all we have given you is comments, not answers; why the demands for substantiation? Why do you care so much?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - if there's a benefit from linkbacks on SEO, stop denigrading the question and post that as an answer (assuming it can be substantiated - my knowledge of SEO and Google ranking is zero so I'm not saynig you're wrong. Just that I need proof)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Comments are for clarifying the question, not denigrading the poster for wanting to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scraper sites are a consequence of the Creative Commons license, not a goal in itself. Their existence isn't really useful at this point as far as I can tell.

The licence is very important, it ensures that the posts here can always be available in some form and that SE can not simply lock them behind a paywall. This ability is not that important while everything goes well, it gets far more important if SE starts to misbehave.

While I don't see any use in the sites that simply copy entire SE sites, I do think that the ability to copy individual posts can be very useful. And copying SE sites as a whole and then building a new community around them, or migrating the community from the original SE site could be a useful option if there are fundamental disagreements between the community and SE. A copycat site becomes far more useful if it continues to add new content, unlike the scraper sites that only copy existing content.

There is at least one site in existence that used the data dump from an SE site and tries to build a new community around it. I strongly disagree with the founders of that site and everything they want to make different than SE, but I think there is value in the ability to fork a site.

Comment: That sounds like open source code approach - there's usually little benefit to HAVING a fork, but there's a major benefit in BEING ABLE to fork. Thanks!