# stackoverflow.usinfonow.com proxy hacking

Tags: support, stack-exchange

It looks like Google's index has been taken over by a man in the middle proxy scheme.

Search Google using `google.com/search?q=usinfonow.com` and `google.com/search?q=stackexchange+usinfonow.com` to see some examples.

Programming related queries on Google that would normally show `stackoverflow.com` pages in the top list of results are now being replaced by the proxy site `stackoverflow.usinfonow.com`.

How do we prevent this in the future? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example of a programming question where this appears? If you have to search for the name of the site it's not an issue.

Comment: If you have to include usinfonow to get them to show up in a search, this would seem to be a pretty "normal" scraper/unauthorized proxy. If so, then take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Maybe this should be asked in Security SE?