# What the @#$% is threadfrage.com?

Tags: discussion, security

While Googling for an earlier answer of mine on mathematica.stackexchange.com I got a hit pointing to http://mathematica.threadfrage.com/ which offers what looks like a complete mirror of the mathematica.se. The same site seems to host many or all of the other stackexchange sites.

My question is whether threadfrage is in any way affiliated with stackexchange and if not, whether it poses any security risk to inattentive users given that it offers the usual SE login and sign-up links on a page that fully resembles the stackexchange page layout and elements.

Comment: Also of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Clicking on some links have a spam popup! Don't trust that site!

Answer (score 15):

> My question is whether threadfrage is in any way affiliated with stackexchange

It is not. It is one of several sites directly [proxying Stack Exchange pages](https://goo.gl/KSXUyt), sometimes outranking the real sites themselves and serving up malware to boot.

> and if not, whether it poses any security risk to inattentive users given that it offers the usual SE login and sign-up links

Quite possibly, although I don't know if there's any indication that this is actively being exploited. Stack Exchange OpenID logins are not necessarily high-value targets, and authenticating against the other external providers will at worst expose profile information on those sites (Facebook, Google, etc.). Hopefully Google will punish such sites with extreme prejudice, and that will be less of a concern.

Comment: Send the First Unicorn Armada on them and all will be good. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - The dreaded f7u12 group?