# What is stackoverflow.xluat.com?

Tags: discussion, clone

I found the website `http://stackoverflow.xluat.com/questions` (edit: do not go there, the site is possibly malicious now) and it seems to be the [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) version of Stack Overflow.

But I cannot find any trace or information about it on SO or SE. Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Report to [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)?

`xluat.com` is registered in Hong Kong, so I don't think it has anything to do with Stack Overflow:

```
Domain Name: xluat.com

Registry Domain ID:
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.onlinenic.com
Registrar URL: http://www.onlinenic.com
Updated Date:
Creation Date: 2015-01-12T04:00:00.0Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2016-01-12T04:00:00.0Z
Registrar: Onlinenic Inc
Registrar IANA ID: 82
Registrar Abuse Contact Email:
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.5107698492
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Domain ID Shield Service
Registrant Organization: Domain ID Shield Service CO., Limited
Registrant Street: 5/F Hong Kong Trade Centre, 161-167 DesVoeux Road Central, Hong Kong
Registrant City: Hong Kong
Registrant State/Province: Hong Kong
Registrant Postal Code: 999077
Registrant Country: CN
Registrant Phone: +852.21581835
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +852.30197491
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email:
```