# stackoverflows.ga has popups and aggressive adverts

Tags: support

stackoverflows.ga is ripping off Stack Overflow. I visited by mistake and I sure did pay for it. I think you should get it shut down. Phrased in the form of a question because I can't submit it otherwise?

Comment: I haven't looked at the site, so I don't know if this applies, but the procedure for reporting license-violating scrapers is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate since that's the fastest way to point you and others who may find this post in the right direction for reporting this to the employees who handle this sort of thing, but I will also pass it along internally.

Comment: I've reported that site [to google](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/?hl=en) some days ago.

Comment: @Anna That is a ridiculous amount of information, I just can't do all that. This is your site I should just be able to hand this issue off to you guys.