# Allow only Stack Exchange sites to link to uploaded images

Tags: discussion, images

Is there a way to prevent non-Stack Exchange sites from linking to uploaded images?

For example look at the following [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150603030519/http://mathematica.stockoverflows.com/).  Doesn't it look familiar?

The image [here](http://mathematica.stockoverflows.com/questions/65970/how-to-obtain-transparent-animated-gif-via-export) is being linked directly to https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUXF8.gif.  I know such functionality is supported because PHP (blaah!) even supports it.

In my opinion it would solve a major security problem. The site above is asking for usernames and passwords.  Hosting costs are a big issue. Most sites don't even bother duplicating the images because of this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Comment: @vaultah Similar but this problem is solvable IMO.

Comment: What images you talk about?? The site copies **everything** from Stack Exchange using server side screen scraping.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no its not check my edit. Images are from the original domain http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUXF8.gif

Comment: So -1 because I would like to be able to link to images I uploaded here from other sites as well, e.g. blog.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The whole **purpose** of imgur is to be a site that lets people hotlink their images.  It's literally the only reason that the site exists.  Preventing people from hotlinking images from the site *that exists to let people hotlink their images* is pretty nonsensical.

Comment: I want a diamond moderator to confirm this. StackExchange has a separate unique domain stack.imgur.com . There has to be a reason for getting a separate domain(they only reason I would get a special domain is for security but there doesn't appear to be any added security benefit).

Answer (score 8):

First, the images aren't StackExchange's, they are hosted on Imgur, an external image service. The images don't belong to SE, it is all licensed under the CC license, so with proper attribution it belongs to everyone.

Second, you didn't give a reason why external sources shouldn't be allowed to access the images. As others said: why won't you want to allow to reuse an image on your blog, or anywhere else. If you don't want to lose control over it, don't post it.

Comment: IMO it solves a major security problem.   The site above is asking for usernames and passwords.  I guess it's just begging for people to copy the site like the example above.

Comment: +1 I agree with Patrick. Liam William add your comment findings to your post.

Comment: @LiamWilliam It is incredibly trivial to copy the images and host them yourself. You're not proposing something that will make an impact on scraper sites; they'll just modify their automated copy tools slightly to account for it.

Comment: As @fbu said. You can view them, so anyone can copy them. No need to deny access from other sites. It doesn't have any use to do that...

Comment: @fbueckert hosting costs are a big issue.  Most sites don't even bother duplicating the images because of the issue.

Comment: They don't care for the images. How many posts have images anyway?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Including the logo link the example above every page.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what exactly the benefit will be except that spammy scraper sites have less useful content.

First of all, those sites don't care about the images, they are only interested in directing traffic to them by having a good SEO. Images are hardly attributing to that.

If you are going to block images from loading from non-stack-exchange sites you also block legitimate uses of the content which can't be the goal of this request.

On top of that the blocking software should be implemented by imgur, not by Stack Exchange.

I think scrapers like the one you found should be reported and all possible means should be employed to shut those sites down. Only blocking part of the content is not going to help much while it does hamper legit use of the content.

Comment: IMO it solves a major security problem. The site above is asking for usernames and passwords

Comment: +1 I agree with you. Also, Stack Exchange should send a DCMA notice to the ISP hosting site.

Comment: @HackerKarma or change to a different site.

Comment: @LiamWilliam what do u mean by "change to a different site"?

Comment: @LiamWilliam I'm not into security that much. How is not showing images solving a major security problem?

Comment: @LiamWilliam The potential risks of Phishing from that site have *nothing* to do with the fact that its hotlinking images.  Forcing it to re-host the images would do nothing to prevent that.

Comment: @Servy hosting costs are a big issue. Most sites don't even bother duplicating the images because of the issue.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Again, that's not going to prevent the site from performing Phishing attacks if that's what it really wants to do.  It might cost them an extra few cents a month, maybe, but that's about it.  Bringing it up as a security issue issue is just absurd.  Stopping hotlinking is in no way a security issue.

Comment: @HackerKarma something other then imgur

Comment: @LiamWilliam You do know that SE pays for the account on imgur?

Comment: @rene Even better reason for imgur to support what I am talking about.