# Is scraping *profiles* (with attribution) allowed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, copyright, screen-scraping

If a site scrapes SE content *with attribution*, and they also scrape SE profiles, is that OK?

I don't see anything about that in [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Answer (score 5):

From the [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) page:

> You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection), without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.

So all contributions should directly point to the profile here on the SE site.

Also, the footer says (emphasis mine):

> **user contributions** licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

And I wonder if the user profile is considered a user contribution. If so, it is allowed to copy the content with attribution, although the link to the author should point to SE, something most scrapers will never do. If this isn't considered a user contribution, it is considered part of the site, which is copyrighted by SE.

In my opinion this falls under user contributions, and therefore it should be allowed to copy the content with attribution, directly linking to the SE profile. Don't know how they would fit that in a design...

Comment: It looks to me that in the first quote that *Hyperlink* should read *hyperlink* lower case, because it is a verb.

Comment: I know. Tell the SE lawyer. ;)

Comment: @JanDoggen To the contrary, both parts of the post appear to conclude that it *is legal* when attribution is included. (Based on my own reading of the ToS and knowledge of CC licenses, I agree that it is legal with attribution.)