# Hidden scraper bet6e.com

Tags: discussion, copyright, screen-scraping

I have a Google alert on my name and this turned up the link http://meta.bet6e.com/users/512728/jan-doggen:

[image]

If you go there you get redirected to a supposed Wordpress blogging site about cloudcomputing at url http://www.cloudcomputingnew.com/

That looks like the [cloaking technique](http://www.itworld.com/article/2738687/security/malware-danger-rises-from-stealth-sites-cloaked-to-be-invisible-to-scanners.html) technique malware sites use: if you visit them from Google search results you get different content then when following a direct link.

If you do a [Google search for bet6e.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=bet6e.com) you see a lot (70000) of links that look like verbatim copies of StackOverflow (including Careers), and they all redirect.
(That profile page above is my SO profile).

The result also turns up some site stats [like this one at website.informer.com](http://website.informer.com/bet6e.com).

I'm mentioning this site for two reasons:

- I doubt that they properly attribute to SE (SO) when they behave like this, but I'm unable to further investigate. I have no idea if/how they are currently (mis)using the data. It could be malware using the cloaking mentioned above.
- They also scrape profiles and I don't see anything about that in [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

So my question is:

Should/can anything be done about bet6e?
I have not filed a [Google webspam report](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport) because I think the criteria over there do not apply
(Specifically, I cannot claim copyright violation with the current knowledge).