# Tag wiki for copycat-sites

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I dropped by earlier today to flag up a site that's scraping SE content and reposting it without attribution. The question was quickly closed with a note pointing me to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/242137). Fair enough. I'd actually tagged my question as [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites), so I suppose I should have done a quick search for this tag before posting.

The tag itself isn't very informative, though. Here is the entire contents of its tag wiki as of right now:

> 

I thought the addition of some actual words might be an improvement, so I suggested this:

> Contributions to Stack Exchange sites are available under a [**cc-by-sa 3.0**](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, which means they can be copied to other sites as long as the original contributors are attributed. Sites that copy content without attribution should be [reported to the Stack Exchange administrators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).
>
> For more information, see the answers to this question:
>
> > [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/242137)

[But my tag wiki edit was rejected for the following reason:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43526)

> *This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.*

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Is the [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) tag wiki *supposed* to be empty?

Comment: That seems odd.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reviewers where maybe a bit to strict on that but according to the wiki guidelines they have a point.

The excerpt and the wiki should explain how and why the tag should be used on questions. If you only provide an explanation of the tag you're missing the important info that we feel needs to be in there.

I normally prevent this kind of mishaps to get enough reputation so my edits don't go in that queue ... wait ... I normally add an opener:

**Excerpt:**

> This tag should be used if your question is about the process of reporting copycat-sites. Don't use it to actually report copycat-sites

**The wiki could go like this:**

> Use this tag for questions that  discuss the process of finding, reporting and/or protecting the content posted on the Stack Exchange Network
>   Topics can include:
>
> - How do I determine attribution
> - What is a violation
> - How do I report
>
> Don't use the tag on question to report sites. Use the procedure [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

I think a text along those line would have been accepted by reviewers.

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Nah, it needs work but you'll get the idea

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you had for the wiki *excerpt:*

> Contributions to Stack Exchange sites are available under a **cc-by-sa 3.0** license, which means they can be copied to other sites as long as the original contributors are attributed. Sites that copy content without attribution should be reported to the Stack Exchange administrators.

A wiki *excerpt* is meant to describe when and why a tag should be used on that site specifically. That might be a big part of why the copy was rejected. It describes the licensing and how to report a scraper, but there is nothing about what the actual tag is for. That information is fine for the actual wiki, but the excerpt does not contain any guidance about the proper use of the tag.

Wikis and excerpts are reviewed as separate entities, but their content goes hand in hand. That might be the source of the problem.

Comment: The excerpt raised a separate review event, apparently. [It was rejected for the same reason.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43527)

Answer (score 1):

I am one of those reviewers and I must admit, I probably used the wrong reject reason... but I still rejected the edit for many reasons.

In terms of editing tag wikis and excerpts, the tag excerpt should briefly explain how and why to use the tag for the question, not explain what the tag means. So I rejected the excerpt edit because it didn't explain how and why you should use this tag for related questions. Instead, make the excerpt and little more leaning on the how and why:

> A tag used for questions about the process of reporting suspected copycat sites. This tag is not meant to be used to actually report copycat sites.

Now for the wiki, the edit doesn't seem to explain much what the tag really is in my opinion. Maybe a little straight-to-the-point and explaining more about the excerpt. So the wiki could be:

> This is a tag that is used for questions about the process of reporting copycat sites that may illegally use Stack Exchange's content. Topics relating to this are:
>
> - What exactly is a violation
> - How do I determine the attribution used
> - How do I report a suspected copycat site.
>
> Please note that this tag should not be used for actual reports of copycat sites.