# Difference between clone and copycat-sites tags?

Tags: discussion, meta, ambiguous-tags, clone, copycat-sites

I've been looking at the [clone](/questions/tagged/clone) [wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/clone/info) and [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) [wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/copycat-sites/info) but I can't understand if there's a difference between the tags.

Do they need a disambiguation? Do they need a merge?

There's been a previous post about clarifying the [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) wiki, see [Tag wiki for copycat-sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276756)

Answer (score 2):

The following portion of the description for [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) leads me to think they should remain separate:

> Questions about sites that copy (or scrape) content from SE

This leads me to think that [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) refers to sites that literally scrape the user content posted on SE and act as an external resource and possibly add some feature that isn't available on SE.

In contrast, the wiki for the [clone](/questions/tagged/clone) tag:

> This tag is used for questions related to various external sites that are clones of the Stack Exchange concept.

The description seems to suggest that it is for a site that uses the same format and/or functionality as SE, but has it's own unique content.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure there is a difference, so I'll leave the question open to see if someone can add more input and an example that draws a clear distinction. (Here's perhaps the problem: such sites are short-lived so producing two examples showing the difference would likely require searching in the WaybackMachine.)