# Filter bogus results when searching for questions/answers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search-engine

I didn't know whether this belonged here or Super User, apologies.

Like many (most?) people I don't search for answers directly on Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites), but rather via Google.

I'm increasingly finding spam at the top of the results, from clone sites which blatantly copy/steal content. Problem is I don't know this when I'm on the search page (it's not like I memorize their names), so I visit the site and end up wasting time before I realise I should read the original content on the original site. It's frustrating and wastes time, and most importantly takes me out of the zone.

I assume we can't do anything about this, as new ones pop up all the time.

Is there an up to date list somewhere with all these copycat sites' domain names? I'd like to use them in a filter in a GreaseMonkey script, to hide those bogus results in my browser.

Comment: You're most probably talking about [SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do?s=1|2.87100). You can help SE prevent this painful experience by reporting them to the staff using "contact us" at the bottom of every SE page.

Comment: @TIPS "Stack Content Republishers Attributing Poorly and/or Excelling at Ranking" Haha what a truly ironic name!

Comment: @Bookend Yeah I usually do a `site:stackoverflow.com foo bar baz` when searching SO specifically. But often I do a general search as well. And then those infernal SCRAPER results pollute the results! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, but I need help.

[First install this userscript](http://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/1682-google-hit-hider-by-domain-search-filter-block-sites). You'll need Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey of course.

Then start with this list I've been using:

```
...removed
```

[refer to list here](http://pastebin.com/A05FXP8p), and note how I broke the URLs so they don't point to the real domains.

*Once you build a good list of SCRAPERs, please link to it.* Lets stop this scourge!

Comment: Please remove the list of sites. They are not listed so far for a good reason, which is to not help them increase their Google ranks. Provide a way to contact you in private if you like to add them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suppose that's a good idea. Removed and replaced with an offsite link.