# Is blogs.candoerz.com a valid copy of serverfault.com?

Tags: discussion

For some reason I decided to Google my name, and this link showed up in results:

http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/250319/ntfs-write-once-files.aspx

The site didn't look familiar at all, but the text there was quite familiar. After searching at serverfault.com, I found an answer I gave over there:

[NTFS Write-Once Files](https://serverfault.com/questions/795774/ntfs-write-once-files)

So, the content of the post at candoerz.com is an exact replica of the question posted and which I have answered here at Serverfault.

Is this a valid clone site, or is the site simply fetching content from serverfault without permission?

Comment: Looks like they are attributing so I think they are fine

Comment: also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do