# A French "clone" of SE?

Tags: discussion

I was looking up info for a [question on Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93520/who-rang-up-mike-to-find-out-where-he-was-after-dan-waxberg-flipped?noredirect=1#comment158205_93520) and found the *exact* same question OP had, but in French on [this site](https://housseniawriting.com/question/explication-de-lintrigue-qui-a-appele-mike-pour-savoir-ou-il-se-trouvait-apres-le-retournement-de-dan-waxberg/).  The OP of the post I was trying to answer did not post this question elsewhere, nor in French.

Looking around there, it looks like the Movies SE questions are being (automatically?) translated in to French and someone's posting over there.  [This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93406/how-did-snape-allow-his-old-advanced-potions-book-to-be-used-by-harry) also has a French "clone" [here](https://housseniawriting.com/question/explication-de-lintrigue-comment-snape-a-t-il-permis-a-harry-dutiliser-son-vieux-livre-de-potions-avancees/)

Is this a "bot site"? I assume there's no affiliation, but they're grabbing questions so I'm just curious what's going on. Is it just bots doing that, and I guess ad revenue is the goal?

Edit: In fact, here's a post with a screenshot [right from SE](https://housseniawriting.com/question/bug-daffichage-de-films-et-de-tournees-de-television/)!

Comment: Read [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/369403). This site copies content without providing proper attribution, the fact that they're also translating is not really relevant I think.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - Ah! That would be it - thanks for that link. (Can we mark this as duplicate? Or should I just delete this)