# Is https://stackoverrun.com/ related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search, google

Recently, I have been getting more and more search results from different search engines that all point to https://stackoverrun.com/. But the original articles that are shown there seem to come from Stack Overflow.

Is the site related to Stack Overflow or is it a fake site? It's very confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do). No, the site is unrelated to SO, but AFAICanSee, the site attributes properly to the source questions and user profile, so IMHO it doesn't need to be reported.

Comment: This looks like a search engine for SO. In fact, the Ask Question button simply links to SO.

Comment: @Bookends. This looks like a Stack Overflow translator. shylynx: Read **everything** in the above linked duplicate origin and follow it's advice or decide not to act.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this site being reported before,either here on MSE or on MSO. But those reports must have been deleted as I can't find it anymore.

Comment: @rene You are? Ok then I take back my answer because the site is then probably malicious...

Comment: I didn't find any previous mentions of this site on MSE (including in deleted posts).