# Code Redirect copying Stack Overflow content?

Tags: discussion

I just came across this website [Code Redirect](https://coderedirect.com/). And I see many questions and answers directly copied from Stack Overflow.

For example, [igraph: Resolving tight overlapping nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290909/igraph-resolving-tight-overlapping-nodes) is a Stack Overflow question and [igraph: Resolving tight overlapping nodes](https://coderedirect.com/questions/257767/igraph-resolving-tight-overlapping-nodes) is the Code Redirect content that is almost identical.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Does it have proper attribution (almost all scraper sites ***don't***) - both author and post attribution? If not, did you [report it](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)?

Comment: No they don't have attribution. In fact, they have replaced the names of original post authors with a different authors.