# SE posts appearing on non-SE sites

Tags: support, copycat-sites

I'm new here. Yesterday I posted a couple of electrical questions in DIY. Later in the day I discovered, by accident when searching for some related material, that my questions also appeared on stucksolver.com and solveforum.com. They're visible on a few other sites as well but the others appear to be connected to SE, or at least they show the SE logo when loaded (e.g. superuser.com, askubuntu.com). stucksolver and solveforum do not appear related to SE. There are posts there from other SE sites, not just DIY.

Is all this expected behavior? Are SE posts supposed to show up elsewhere like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

Regarding superuser.com and askubuntu.com, they're both Stack Exchange sites (some are like sitename.stackexchange.com, some have their own domain name). Looking at [the timeline for your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/255988/timeline), it says "became hot network question":

[image: screenshot of question timeline]

A "hot network question" is when a question reaches a threshold hotness score as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/152859). This basically means it has a chance of appearing on the right sidebar ([obligatory freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/1081494))

[image: screenshot of Hot Network Questions sidebar]

Regarding the other sites, no, they are not SE. See the MSE (this site) post titled [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do) for more info on that, as Rubén noted

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Before posting I looked for someplace where this question had been asked, but I didn't quite use the same terminology in my search so I missed the prior answer. I read the post and understand that what they're doing is allowed by the license used.

Comment: @trawson no it's not allowed and not following any license, sites like "stucksolver.com" just steal content and publish it as their own, while adding their own ads to make money. That's no different from stealing items from a shop and illegal in most countries in the world.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard OK now I'm confused, but that happens :). So it's not allowed, but also not something SE pursues because they don't own the content, the posters do? If that's the case I don't see why they don't assert a collection copyright, but then that's not an issue I would want to go after.

Comment: @trawson in the linked duplicate, under "What is a "scraper" and why is that bad" it says: *so long as they follow the attribution requirements and link back to us as the source.*. sites like "stucksolver.com" do not link back and break the attribution requirements hence illegal.