What, exactly, is Stack Overflow's agreement with OpenAI?
It's difficult to know what, exactly, the accord between Stack Overflow and OpenAI is. Per the meta announcement:

anything specific promised about how this will work here could change

but that's about technical details. Presumably, the legal side of things is already drawn up: that's what I'd like to know. (Or if it's not, and this is just a declaration of intent? I'd like to know that, too.) We have hints, but so far they're contradictory.

Rosie says that “Having credit attributed is a non-negotiable for us” and “making sure attribution is happening (in a license-compliant way) is a commitment we require and have received from our partners”.

Unless they've made substantial theoretical progress and are keeping it very secret, OpenAI does not have the technology to train models on our work while retaining attribution.
By implication, the company will not let OpenAI train their transformer models on Stack Exchange contributions, and OpenAI has committed not to.


But the press release says:

OpenAI will utilize Stack Overflow’s OverflowAPI product and collaborate with Stack Overflow to improve model performance for developers who use their products. This integration will help OpenAI improve its AI models using enhanced content and feedback from the Stack Overflow community and provide attribution to the Stack Overflow community within ChatGPT to foster deeper engagement with content.


Does "improve its AI models" mean using our contributions as training data?
Unlike Wikipedia, Stack Overflow contributions cannot be attributed merely to "Stack Overflow contributors" (the usual terms of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license apply), but it sounds like that's what the press release says they'll do. Contradiction.


Is this side of the partnership perhaps restricted to glorified search results, à la chat oneboxes?

OpenAI will also surface validated technical knowledge from Stack Overflow directly into ChatGPT,

suggests they might be planning that. If that's all, then this whole fuss has been over very little.


The ambiguity helps nobody. I don't need $numbers, but I want terms. It's our work you're selling, it's our communities you're hurting. We have a right to know.

What is Stack Overflow providing OpenAI?
What are OpenAI's obligations with regards to the provided material?

Specifically, is Stack Exchange licensing or planning to license subscriber content to OpenAI under anything other than CC-BY-SA?


What are the actual words of that agreement?


If we get an answer from a lawyer, please be kind: lawyers are not usually responsible for strategic decision-making, and shooting the messenger is a bad strategy (also, it's mean). If a bigwig answers, please consider the tactical value of punching up here and now, given the context. I don't think anyone needs a reminder to be nice to CMs.

Can I suggest adding "Is StackExchange planning to license subscriber content to OpenAI under anything other than a CC-BY-SA?" There is some ambiguous wording in the ToS that suggests this might be possible. It would explain what OpenAI is getting out of the deal (since they have all subscriber content already under CC-BY-SA).

"We have a right to know." Morally, or socially, sure, but technically, I don't think so. (Which is another way the community can potentially be dealt a disastrous blow when it comes to the mutual trust and respect that has been eroding for a while now.)

The best case scenario is they are selling access to an API a chatbot can use to pull in live information linking back to the network. Ideally then that money goes back into supporting public Q&A and ancillary development as well as hires. That said there's no guarantee that a cc compliant agreement means it will be fully honoured or that the revenue would be wisely reinvested into the community.

It is unfortunate that while this appears to have already been done, there is no real recourse for what happens when these training sets simply "clean" off the attribution as noise; as is already being done. EleutherAI even lists Stack Exchange as part of its source material, and they do note that their training material has data removed such as attribution; as is done for all content gleaned from crawling. Crawling used to be illegal and content scraped would have a DMCA removal order. Clearly that is no longer the case, and scraping is now being institutionalized.

I understand that there are a lot of questions about our partnership with OpenAI and what this means in terms of attribution. While I can’t answer every bullet point or all of the questions on the main Meta Post announcement, I want to be clear about our attribution agreement with any Overflow API partners.
In our agreements with our partners, we have stated that the data they use is governed by the Creative Commons license.
The precise Creative Commons license that governs each piece of content depends on the date the content was published or edited (see Creative Commons Licensing UI and Data Updates - Meta Stack Exchange)

Content contributed before 2011-04-08 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of CC BY-SA 2.5.
Content contributed from 2011-04-08 up to but not including 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of CC BY-SA 3.0.
Content contributed on or after 2018-05-02 (UTC) is distributed under the terms of CC BY-SA 4.0.

The dataset API partners have access to contains license information for every Post, Question, Answer, Revision, Comment, and Question_Timeline (type=revision). The history of a post will always indicate which license applies to that post.
This means that we have supplied the information for them to comply with the Creative Commons requirement to provide “appropriate credit” per Creative Commons. The definition of “appropriate credit” per Creative Commons is “the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice, a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material. CC licenses prior to Version 4.0 also require you to provide the title of the material if supplied, and may have other slight differences.”
We are not solutioning (aka, directing or telling) how our partners meet these requirements for attribution and appropriate credit.
I hope this provides a bit more clarity.

this is good news. though note that this does not fully answer the question(s).

So effectively, access to packaged licensed content was sold to openai/google under the promise that they'd respect the license, but no instructions or requirements past that are being enforced to ensure the license is being respected. Is this something the company will enforce for us? or is the community on it's own against these giants to ensure they're following the license you are selling our content under?

This misrepresents what the CC BY-SA license says. Section 3(a)(2) of the license allows the entity exercising the rights to "satisfy the conditions" of the Attribution clause "in any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context...". This gives a lot of flexibility. On top of this, because of 3(a)(1)(A)(v), a simple URI or hyperlink to a SE network question is sufficient. There's actually no need to credit each individual who wrote a post. So your definition of "appropriate credit" (which is never used in the CC license) doesn't match the reality of what the license exams.

Are there procedures for yanking revisions when moderators redact them? That only happens rarely, but it's very important most times it happens.

@ThomasOwens I don't think Rosie is misrepresenting anything: this is an adequate summary of the §3(a)(1)(A) obligations. §3(a)(2) says that a hyperlink may be a reasonable way to satisfy those obligations, but doesn't replace those obligations. (If, for example, they're using deleted material, where the hyperlink will point nowhere, a hyperlink is clearly not reasonable attribution.) §3(a)(1)(A)(i) says “in any reasonable manner requested by the Licensor”: by posting on Stack Exchange, I think the Stack Exchange definition of "appropriate credit" (which dates way back) can be assumed.

@KevinB, I encourage you to be more precise in your summary.  Nowhere did this response say that OpenAI/Google promised to respect the license.  It says that Stack Exchange stated to them that the material is licensed under Creative Commons.  I think it's sufficiently clear that Stack Exchange has not made any promises to enforce this for us (same as it has been before the agreement, like it or not).  See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/160917

@wizzwizz4 That is incorrect. SE can't set additional terms on top of CC BY-SA, as specified in Section 2(a)(5)(C). The user of the content is responsible for determining how to meet the requirements of Section 3(a). The use of terms like "reasonable" are very vague and would likely require negotiation. However, such negotiation would need to be between the author of the post and the recipient of the licensed content - SE does not obtain permission to act on our behalf.

My key point here is that what I think is "appropriate credit" is actually very different than what the CC BY-SA license requires for attribution. Just because partners are receiving information doesn't mean they have to display it or display it in a way that an individual may think is appropriate or reasonable. And only the owners of the content can take any action to enforce the terms. However, as I personally found out, enforcing the attribution clauses is very difficult due to their ambiguity and vaguity.

@ThomasOwens In the absence of negotiation, "reasonable" is what's considered reasonable. People have been saying Stack Exchange can't legally require this attribution format for years, but I've seen nobody say that the Stack Exchange interpretation isn't reasonable. By posting on Stack Exchange, and expressing no opinion otherwise, shouldn't the contents of the Help Center guidance be considered the format implicitly requested by the Licensor? (The difficulty of us enforcing license compliance on orgs like OpenAI is a separate matter, and a more relevant one.)

@wizzwizz4 I'm not saying anything about how SE interprets or provides attribution. This post reads as if the SE partners (Google, OpenAI, others in the future) must provide attribution that includes "the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice, a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material". This is not true, as stated in the CC BY-SA license. (1/2).

Thanks for this answer. But is this good news? As I'd understand it, this says the data OpenAI is receiving comes with the same licence as the public dump. ...Which OpenAI is already using without proper attribution. So why should we assume that they will honour the licence any more when the data comes through the API? It seems evident that the AI companies are banking on a court decision that training models is fair use, and copyright can be treated with blatant disregard.

@wizzwizz4 Also, SE is not the Licensor - the content author is the Licensor. So if a content author has a disagreement with how Google or OpenAI or someone else is attributing their post, the author has to take it up with them. And, as I've personally found out, the "any reasonable manner" wording in Section (3)(a)(2) give a lot of latitude to the person using the CC BY-SA content. It's often not worth pursuing anything related to attribution if there's at least a half-assed attempt to attribute somehow. (2/2)

"I hope this provides a bit more clarity." Thank you. Yes it does provide a bit of clarity. Basically instead of scraping the website or the data dumps they can use the API now. On the other hand, how they can offer that data without giving attribution in their products is still a mystery and will probably remain so for some time. SO, the company, is probably not willing to help with persecution of CC license violations of the content here, or does it?

@leftaroundabout "..the AI companies are banking on a court decision that training models is fair use.." But at least now they have to gamble on that. It could be worse. This will be a really monumental court case and the ultimately test for fair use. Probably with lots of money stakes on all sides because of AI companies on one side and all other content producers on the other side.

@ThomasOwens "...at least a half-assed attempt to attribute somehow..." With ChatGPT however there is no attempt whatsorever to attribute and given the multitude of sources being used, it's hard to even technically do that. I imagine a very long footnote list.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Yeah. I haven't seen or been able to get ChatGPT to attribute anything. A core function of Gemini is finding supporting material on the Internet for claims, but there are questions about if that supporting material was part of the input material and if it's really the right thing to attribute. There are also open questions about attributing the content used to train models. So plenty of open questions, but as far as I'm concerned, this is a non-answer since it misrepresents what CC BY-SA says, what SE can do, and the state of attribution in GenAI in general.

"We are not solutioning (aka, directing or telling) how our partners meet these requirements for attribution and appropriate credit." Does lead to a question of what happens if the partners disreguard the attribution. The nature of the feed/API allows people to do the right thing, but what happens if they choose not to?

To be fair, supervising how these large corporations are gaining their AI training material isn't a responsibility of SO. That's a matter for governments, and in case there's suspicions about license violation/piracy, a matter for the police. Which I suppose would be the FBI in this case, given that SO is based out of New York. So in case anyone has actual evidence of OpenAI or other corporations stealing licensed material in order to profit from it, report it to the relevant police authority.

So, exactly... since you call them partner but at the same time "We are not solutioning (aka, directing or telling) how our partners meet these requirements for attribution and appropriate credit." exactly what makes the "partner" instead of users? Why would they pay for a dump that they can easily get for free like they already did before (since it is easy to demonstrate that the biggest LLM on the market include network post in their training material)?  And more importantly, what about this user claim?

Well, that's nice legalese for saying "we don't really care". Of course SO know that all LLMs, including OpenAI's are technically and on principal grounds incapable of meeting the requirement of attribution. Looking the other way and subjecting all members of SO to a glaring misuse of their content is just not the right thing to do, ethically and legally. Not only does it destroy trust it also hurts the community badly.

@miraculixx LLMs, including OpenAI's, have already trained on SO data without any attribution or any promise to attribute, under the theory that attribution is not required because they are covered by Fair Use and similar limits to copyright rights. In the worst-case scenario that they do nothing at all to improve on this attribution (which, like you, I am skeptical they even can do), users creating content for SO are in no worse shape than they were before.

@BryanKrause I see what you mean, however I disagree. If anything, the situation is now worse for SO users, because SO have contractually agreed instead of standing up for their and their user's respective rights.

@miraculixx SO does not have any authority to pursue copyright claims on your behalf. I would instead characterize this as SO getting the most they can possibly get out of a contract without having much to offer that AI companies weren't already taking. It seems like they're basically paying for a little bit of goodwill by at least partly funding the operations of SO that keep the content available to users in the form that it currently is.

It does feel like a bit of a cop-out to say you're "not solutioning (aka, directing or telling) how our partners meet these requirements for attribution and appropriate credit"
This entire deal was inked and no one even bother to talk to them HOW they would potentially navigate the CC licensing of all the content covered in the agreement?
It seems hard to believe that proper, license appropriate use of the content never came up.

@BryanKrause Clearly there is a difference between scenarios where a) SO says "this data shall not be used unless in line with the license terms, and we'll stand up for our user's rights", or b) "you can use the data if you give us $$$ and the rest is up to each individual user". I would have expected SO chose scenario a), after all the only reason they exist is due to their users and the user's content. Also I think they can't argue, at least ethically, that choosing b) is right.

@miraculixx Except the people using it and their lawyers believe those license terms don't apply to them, so SO can say a) as loud as they want, it doesn't have any effect (and they also do not have any rights to enforce those terms because they are not the actual copyright owner, they've just licensed the content from us). If they went with a) it would be just meaningless grandstanding to convince their users they're doing good by them while actually doing nothing. b) I would instead phrase as "We'll take some $ to maintain the site", which is the most they can do by their users.

@BryanKrause Of course saying no has an effect, mainly it upholds a legal standpoint. Agreeing to the use of the data (that, as you rightfully note, is not their's to begin with) knowing the license terms will be broken, has the opposite effect, mainly it removes any way to enforce those rights and it destroys trust.

@miraculixx Can you explain which license term was enforceable before the agreement (and by whom) and is not enforceable after the agreement?

@BryanKrause so you're saying the CC BY SA license is really just for naught?

@miraculixx I'm saying that the person who can enforce a license is the copyright holder. In the case of content you create, that's you.

@Rosie Will the company commit, in clear and binding terms, to pursue legal action should the license not be sufficiently honored? Or, if you take the stance of a lot of these comments that it's our responsibility to meet OpenAI in court, will the company commit to support community members in their suit, either by providing legal support or by filing generous amicus briefs? Anything? Any commitment at all to enforcement?

@samuei: It is not legal for the company to do that, unless you transfer the copyright to them or give them an exclusive license (which CC-BY-SA isn't). It is not possible, under US law, to transfer a naked "right to sue" for copyright infringement, according to the Ninth Circuit. If you, personally, are not prepared to sue to defend your copyright, then your copyright functionally doesn't exist.
